# Add day to a Date without button and while using Model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to enter two fields, one is initial date, the other is time limit (`int`), after that, I need to show (without button) the resulting date in a `EditorFor`.

This is my `View`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.inicial_date, new { HtmlAttributes = new {@id = "inicial_date", @class = "datepicker form-control", @onkeyup = "sumdate();" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.time_limit, new { HtmlAttributes = new { @id = "time_limit", @class = "form-control", @onkeyup = "sumdate();" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.final_date, new { HtmlAttributes = new { @id = "final_date", @class = "form-control" } })
```

And my Javascript function is this:

```
function sumdate() {
        var inicialDate = document.getElementById('inicial_date').value;
        var timeLimit= document.getElementById('time_limit').value;
        var finalDate= inicialDate.changDay() + parseInt(timeLimit);
        if (!isNaN(finalDate)) {
            document.getElementById('final_date').value = finalDate;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what exactly didn't work? Is your sumdate() function executed? Do you get console errors? What does the `changDay()` method do? Bear in mind that `inicialDate` is a string, and I don't know of any method called changDay() which can be executed on a string. Are you wanting to add `timeLimit` number of days to the date in inicialDay? You probably need to parse it as a `Date` object first.

Comment: I dont have console errors, just didn't show result date. Yes, inicial Date is a string, I gonna try to parse it as a Date right now.

Comment: Sorry but it's impossible with that code that you don't have console errors. See https://jsfiddle.net/pmdhnczn/1/ - open up your console, start typing in the textbox, and you'll see the error "Uncaught TypeError: inicialDate.changDay is not a function". Unless your code is not running at all, you will have something similar. I assume you know what I mean by looking in the browser console.

Comment: you are right, I wasn't looking the brownser console, I have that error "getElementById is not defined
    at sumdate (IngresarPrueba:352)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (IngresarPrueba:306)".